# What relation do glycerol-3-P DH and acyl-CoA DH have with Complex II of the ETC?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, nomenclature, definitions, energy-metabolism

I am sorry if this may be a purely definitional/nomenclature question.

Complex II of the electron transport chain (ETC) would be succinate dehydrogenase, transporting electrons to ubiquinone (and forming ubiquinol with the addition of 2 protons).

Both glycerol-3-phosphate dehydrogenase (DH) and acyl CoA DH are integrated in the inner mitochondrial membrane, and form an ubiquinol, which can be used by Complex III of the ETC - very similarly to succinate DH. I was wondering why, then, these 2 enzymes weren't also part of "Complex II" or whether they were just not part of an "ETC complex" because they aren't part of the TCA cycle, or something? Are they in any way also related to the ETC supercomplex/respirasome?

Thank you.